# $A_4$ is not the direct product of its sylow subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

This is an exercise in Hungerford. I've tried proving this as follows (forgetting for the moment that in $A_4$, $n_2=1$ and $n_3=4$):

By Sylow III, $n_2=1$ or $3$.

If $n_2=3$, the number of elements of order $2$ in $A_4$ is $n_2 (2-1)=3(2-1)=3.$ Then the number of elements of order not $3$ is $12-3=9$. Let $P$ be a Sylow $3$-subgroup. $|P|=3$ Number of elements we have to fill up this subgroup with exceeds the number of elements of this subgroup, hence the Sylow $3$-subgroup is not normal and $A_4$ not the direct product of its sylow subgroups.

Suppose next $n_2=1$. Again by Sylow III, $n_3=1$ or $4$. If $n_3=1$, then there are 6 elements in $A_4$, which is a contradiction. Hence $n_3 = 4$ then the Sylow $3$-subgroup is not normal and again $A_4$ is not the direct product of its Sylow subgroups.

Any corrections and/or alternative proofs are welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a counting argument in your third paragraph. A Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal (inded, characteristic) if and only if $n_p = 1$. Combine this with the fact that no product of subgroups can be direct unless the subgroups are all normal.

Comment: Well the obvious reason this cannot be correct, is that this uses absolutely nothing about $A_4$. All of your arguments (if correct) would apply to any group which is order 12. But there are of course groups which are order 12 and abelian and hence the direct product of their sylow subgroups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *many* incorrect statements in your proof.

Anyway, this is beside the point as you can prove this statement quickly without counting Sylow subgroups, or doing any other hard analysis:

Assume $A_4$ is a direct product of its Sylow subgroups. The Sylow 2-subgroups of $A_4$ have order 4, hence are abelian. Similarly, the Sylow 3-subgroups are abelian. If $A_4$ is a direct sum of Sylow subgroups, then $A_4$ must be abelian, **a contradiction**.

OR

If $A_4$ is a direct product of its Sylow subgroups, then each Sylow subgroup is normal (i.e. $n_p=1$ for $p=2,3$). However, $(123)$ and $(124)$ generate distinct Sylow 3-subgroups. Hence, $A_4$ is **not** a direct sum of its Sylow subgroups.